# Fast Refreshable MView creation ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, fast-refresh

I want to create m-view which keeps the aggregates of cash from transaction history.

The query is as follows.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_CASH_STATS

BUILD IMMEDIATE REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND 
AS

( -- Total aggregates 
    SELECT
        'total' AS CODE
        , COUNT(T.CASH_IN) AS DEPOSITS
        , COUNT(T.CASH_OUT) AS WITHDRAWS
        , SUM(T.CASH_IN) AS DEPOSIT
        , SUM(T.CASH_OUT) AS WITHDRAW
    FROM
        TB_CASH_LOG T
)
UNION ALL
( -- Aggregates by account grades
    SELECT
        'grade-' || T1.GRADE AS CODE
        , COUNT(T.CASH_IN) AS DEPOSITS
        , COUNT(T.CASH_OUT) AS WITHDRAWS
        , SUM(T.CASH_IN) AS DEPOSIT
        , SUM(T.CASH_OUT) AS WITHDRAW
    FROM
        TB_CASH_LOG T
        INNER JOIN TB_ACCOUNT T1 ON
            T.ACCOUNT_ID = T1.ID
    GROUP BY T1.GRADE
)
```

When i execute this, the following error occurs.

```sql
> ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
```

(I created m-view log tables for both `TB_CASH_LOG` and `TB_ACCOUNT`)

The `Total aggregates` part is ok, but the later part - `Aggregates by account grades` - makes the error.

I've read [Oracle basic materialized view docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8208), and thinking that `INNER JOIN` or `GROUP BY` is the error point.

If it is true, **fast refresh m-view** with `inner join` and `group by` is impossible?
What is wrong with my m-view declaration sql?

p.s. I'm working on oracle 18c

Comment: If you scroll up a little bit in the documentation you linked to, it shows restrictions on using `union all`. It may not be the only issue but you don't have [a `union all` marker](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/qradv.htm#BABEAHIA). There is also a section on [analysing your view query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8218). (I'd also suggest you use the documentation for 18c, not 11g.)

Comment: I know ANSI join does not work. You have to use the old Oracle join Syntax `from TB_CASH_LOG T, TB_ACCOUNT`

Comment: Maybe [DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67191) helps you

Comment: @AlexPoole I tested with comment first part and `union all` - meaning tested only the second part - the error is same.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tested oracle sql join, as you mentioned, `from TB_CASH_LOG T, TB_ACCOUNT T1`, the result is same :(

Comment: Have a look at [Materialized Views with Aggregates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG8175): *"the SELECT list must contain all of the GROUP BY columns (if present), and there must be a COUNT(*) and a COUNT(column) on any aggregated columns"* At least `count(*)` is missing. `'grade-' || T1.GRADE` may not be sufficient, try `T1.GRADE` only

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit WOW, the error's gone, after I add 'raw' `T1.GRADE`. But, `UNION ALL` is the another problem. I think it's not allowed for fast refresh mv, is it?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit And, when I see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B), it seems that `union` can be usable but when I see [above](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B__I2119766), it's impossible. What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Don't mistake `UNION ALL` with `UNION`!